# How do I upgrade its OS to windows 10 in SAFE mode?

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode

I've genuine windows 7 laptop(Sony vaio - i3).
My system is too slow in normal mode that win10 installer does not run.
But it's system is faster if I'm in safe mode.
How do I upgrade my OS to windows 10 in SAFE mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try and fix the issue of your computer running slow. There are lot of things that can make your system run slow.  But you should try run cleanup and defrag ur hard drive. Also disable some start up programs and reduce apps running in background.

Concerning upgrading to Windows 10, it is not necessary you have to use media creation tool. You can download an ISO file online and create an installation media with it. You can get windows 10 iso file from websites like getintopc. Less I forgot, try and download November update ISO file.